# How to program over match.call?

Tags: r, arguments, match

I'm trying to program over a function inside a package, but I'm stuck with the function internally using `match.call()` to parse one of its arguments.

A super-simplified example of the function with the usual utilization could look like this:

```
f1 = function(x, y=0, z=0, a=0, b=0){ #lots of arguments not needed for the example
  mc = match.call()
  return(mc$x)
  #Returning for testing purpose.
  #Normally, the function later uses calls as character:
  r1 = as.character(mc$x[1])
  r2 = as.character(mc$x[2])
  #...
}
x1 = f1(x = foo(bar))
x1
# foo(bar)
class(x1)
# [1] "call"
```

In my case, I need to get the value of `x` from a variable (`value` in the following code). Expected utilisation of `f1` is as following :

```
value = "foo(bar)" #this line could also be anything else
f1(x=some_magic_function(value))
# Expected result = foo(bar)
# Unwanted result = some_magic_function(value)
```

Unfortunately, `match.call()` always return the very input value. I'm quite out of my league here so I only tried few functions.

**Is there any way I could trick `match.call()` so it could accept external variable ?**

Failed attempts so far:

```
#I tried to create the exact same call using rlang::sym()
#This may not be the best way...
value = call("foo", rlang::sym("bar"))
value
# foo(bar)
class(value)
# [1] "call"
x1==value
# [1] TRUE

f1(x=value)
# value
f1(x=eval(value))
# eval(value)
f1(x=substitute(value))
# substitute(value)
```

Comment: I don't fully understand your requirements but maybe `eval(substitute(f1(value), list(value = value)))`?

Comment: Could you please be more verbose on what you are trying to achieve? I cannot understand it from the description, especially the _abstractise the value of `x` so I can use it in another function._

Comment: @Roland This would work, but since there is a lot of arguments I would like `f1` to be the first member of the pipeline.

Comment: @Jozef you are right, I edited my post, is it any clearer ?

Comment: @DanChaltiel, in your desired output of `f1(x=some_magic_function(value))`, what is the `foo(bar)` (is it a character string `"foo(bar)"`, is a call to `foo` with 1 argument `bar`, or something else) ?

Comment: @Jozef OK this was lost in translation (and corrected). This example is not e desired output but a desired utilization. I don't really care of the output of `f1`, I only want it to use the value of `value` instead of the argument call. Actually, the comment of Roland is working perfectly, I'd just rather want the function to be applied on `value` than on `f1`.

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing you can include as a parameter to `f1` to make this work. Instead, you would dynamically need to build your call to `f1`. With base R you might do this with `do.call`.

```
do.call("f1", list(parse(text=value)[[1]]))
```

or with rlang

```
eval_tidy(quo(f1(!!parse_expr(value))))
```

Comment: Too bad but I was expecting such an answer. Your examples are very interesting too but I'll stick with the one @Roland commented.